# Google Compute Engine Windows Server Ports

Tags: tomcat, server, google-cloud-messaging

I just made a new VM using GCE with windows server 2008.
I ran tomcat to establish a new webserver , when running localhost:8080 or InternalIp:8080 everything is fine but when using the externalip:8080 page isn't found even from the VM itself not from my computer.
so is there any routes i should add or whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just disabled my windows server firewall all working fine now
Need only to add a new rule